# Connecting Dual Dell U2415 Monitors to Closed Macbook Pro (15" Retina, Mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch Retina, Mid 2012) with 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB.  It has two Thunderbolt ports and one HDMI port.

I want to connect two Dell U2415 24-inch monitors at 1920 x 1200 at 60Hz with the MacBook closed.  I'm prefer for them to be daisy chained.  And have one monitor vertical (that probably doesn't factor into anything)

Is this possible?  What would be the best way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've retracted my post as I didn't see that this was a 2012 machine, thus this is not possible.